# Hibernate just insert first time

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

```
@Entity
public class Human {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerateType.AUTO)
    int id;
    String name;
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PessoaFisicaBean {

   Human human = new Human();
   HumanDaoImp dao = new HumanDaoImp();

   public void add() {    
       dao.add(human);      
   }    
}
```

if i use this, it only work in first time, in the second will work like merge, but i have the persist:

DaoIMP ->

```
public void add(Human human) {

   entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
   entityManager.persist(human);
   entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

but if i edit the managedbean in this way:

```
public void add() {    
    dao.add(human);     
    human = new Human();
}
```

it works flawless, however i will never be able to "recover" the last insert, since after the .add it clean the human for new one, and i cant understand why in the persist it dont create another id, use the same =(

Obs: using PostGreSQL
Obs2: JSF + Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your method likes this;

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PessoaFisicaBean {

   HumanDaoImp dao = new HumanDaoImp();

   public void add() {
       Human human = new Human();//New object
       dao.add(human);      
   } 

   public void edit() {
       Human human = getHuman();//Old object that want to edit
       dao.edit(human);      
   }    

}
```

In your DAOImpl

```
 public void add(Human human) {
      entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
      entityManager.persist(human);
      entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
   }

public void edit(Human human) {
      entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
      entityManager.merge(human);
      entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
   }
```

So you don't need to worry which is persist or merge.

Answer (score 0):

After the first time you persist the human, this human object becomes "managed entity", which means the ORM identified this object. The second time you persist it, the ORM thinks "this is not a new entity, we already know it", so the behavior is like "merge".

Comment: how can i change it to everytime i click Save, it insert a new one?

Comment: i think i will solve it just adding a human = new Human();, i dont know how to solve without it

Comment: Yes, this is the normal way. An alternative is to use [entityManager.detach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach(java.lang.Object))

Comment: In addition, you can test that after you persist the newly created human object, the @Id value of it is set by ORM